# Javascript assigning value to variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to make a cell in a table tell me its number when I click it.

```
for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
    var cell = row.insertCell(j);
    cell.name = j;
    cell.onclick=function(){alert(cell.name)};
}
```

This however, prints the number 8 for every cell. How do I save the value of `j` in `cell.name`, instead of just having it point to the variable `j`?

Thanks.

Comment: But going off your code, your `cell` reference appears to be constant?

Comment: Where do you initialize `cell`?

Comment: If you have only one cell, this isn't going to work.

Comment: Change `cell` so it points to different cells in each iteration.

Comment: I have added the "var cell = row.insertCell(j);" Think that is what you ment?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMPORTANT: All JavaScript developers should know this. It will cause all kinds of weird bugs that is very hard to find.

It is a common mistake of people who are new to JavaScript. I've made the same mistake before.

A function inside a loop is NOT created for every iteration. It is the same one function object with the same closure scope. Thus, your cells will have the exact same onclick callback.

My advice here is NEVER EVER create a function inside of loop. Instead, create and call a function that returns a callback function and assign it to onclick.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(j);
    cell.name = j;
    cell.onclick = createOnClick(cell);
}

function createOnClick(cell) {
    return function () {
        // do whatever you want to do with cell
    };
}
```

Comment: Something like this? function a(name) {
    function b(name){
        alert(name); 
    }
    return b();
}

Comment: I will give you an example in few minutes once I turn on my laptop.

Comment: This worked. I placed the "alert(cell.name)" inside the returned function and it now work as intended. Thanks alot :)